# How to read excel file with multiple sheets from python? I got error saying 'pandas' has no attribute 'excel'

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, import, openpyxl

## At first, I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f)
    all_data = all_data.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

now save the data frame

```
Covid_Apr2022_data = pd.excel('Covid-19 April to May 2022 data only.xlsx')
all_data.to_excel(Covid_Apr2022_data)
Covid_Apr2022_data.save() 

sheet1 = xls.parse(0)
```

I got the error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/1438062488.py in <module>
      8 
      9 # now save the data frame
---> 10 Covid_Apr2022_data = pd.excel('Covid-19 April to May 2022 data only.xlsx')
     11 all_data.to_excel(Covid_Apr2022_data)
     12 Covid_Apr2022_data.save()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in __getattr__(name)
    242         return _SparseArray
    243 
--> 244     raise AttributeError(f"module 'pandas' has no attribute '{name}'")
    245 
    246 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'excel'
```

## I also gave another attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('../input/covid19-april-2022-data/Covid-19 April to May 2022 data only.xlsx', sheet_name = None)
```

But got this ImportError:

```
Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

Then I install 'openpyxl', but it can't recognize it as the module.

Comment: `Covid_Apr2022_data = pd.excel('Covid-19 April to May 2022 data only.xlsx')` Change `pd.excel` to `pd.read_excel`

Comment: Tried pd.excel_read, error says it cant recognize its file or directory.  I also tried full path but still not working.  Just wondering if it requires excelWriter or import xlsrwriter but I only work on Kaggle at the moment.  It seems require xlrd too but after imported, it still says No module named 'xlrd'.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the environment in which you're installing openpyxl

```
source <env_name>/bin/activate
pip install openpyxl
```

or maybe try installing using conda:

```
conda install -n <env_name> openpyxl
```

Comment: I checked the dir and the openpyxl is there: >>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> os.path.dirname(sys.executable) .  So I guess it should be still some unsolved issues with having excel multiple sheets from python.  checked similar answers but still not working for my case.

Comment: Tried use Jupyter Notebook and could at least ensure the whole workbook with multiple sheets. solution is:  data = pd.read_excel(filepath).  But still it cant be one off whole notebook as head and tail prompted.  It has to add 0 to 30 at the end of coding to get each of multiple sheets covered.